# Using Echo statement writes Echo is ON in the text file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xp-cmdshell

Following code is used for write a number in the text file but instead it is writing "Echo is ON" into the text file.

```
SET @CMD = 'ECHO '+@Ver+'>'+@Vercheck      
  Print @CMD

EXEC xp_cmdshell @CMD  
  ,NO_OUTPUT
```

Print @CMD  gives  "ECHO 1>C:\Pharmsuite\Vercheck.txt"

Here instead of 1, the query is writing "Echo is ON".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This command: `ECHO 1>C:\Pharmsuite\Vercheck.txt`

Does not do what you think it should do because 1> has a special meaning.

This problem can be fixed by adding a space before `>`:

```
ECHO 1 >C:\Pharmsuite\Vercheck.txt
```

Or in your case:

```
SET @CMD = 'ECHO '+@Ver+' >'+@Vercheck
```

It also works with this command (making sure there is a space before `ECHO` [thanks to Andriy M]):

```
SET @CMD = '>'+@Vercheck+' ECHO '+@Ver
```

You should look at:

- Technet [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)
- SS64 [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

> Numeric handles:
>
> STDIN  = 0  Keyboard input
>   STDOUT = 1  Text output
>   STDERR = 2  Error text output
>   UNDEFINED = 3-9
>
> command 2> filename       Redirect any error message into a file
>      command 2>> filename      Append any error message into a file
>     (command)2> filename       Redirect any CMD.exe error into a file

Anyhow, you should avoid using `xp_cmdshell`. If you are trying to output something, Powershell or SQL Server command line commands are better options.

Using Powershell and [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc281720%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT GETDATE() AS TimeOfQuery;" -ServerInstance "MyComputer\MyInstance"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\MyFolder\TestSQLCmd.sql" | Out-File -filePath "C:\MyFolder\TestSQLCmd.rpt"
```

You obviously have to adapt it to your own requierements and you must also look at Daniel Hutmacher's answer using osql.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, `1>` has a specific meaning. It means "redirect standard output", whereas `2>` would be "redirect standard error". `>` by itself is short-hand for `1>`.

You can try:

```
SET @CMD = 'ECHO>'+@Vercheck + ' ' + @Ver
```

Since you can perform redirection before the rest of the arguments to `echo`.

Answer (score 5):

**Alternate solution**

Instead of using `xp_cmdshell`, which comes with a lot of security risks, you could run something like this from the command prompt:

```
osql >output_file.txt -S myServer\myInstance -E -Q "PRINT @@VERSION"
```

The -S switch denotes the name of the server and instance, -E means Windows authentication (you could instead use -U and -P for username and password), and -Q is the actual query. Note that I've used PRINT instead of SELECT in order to get rid of the column headers.

Obviously, you could replace "PRINT @@VERSION" with any valid T-SQL code.

Comment: Just curious, why recommend **osql** instead of **sqlcmd** ? **osql** has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 was released, which introduced **sqlcmd**. Is there a benefit to using **osql**?